# How to gets some metadata when cursor observer notify change

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider

When i got some cursor i want to be aware for changes, so i have used the `registerContentObserver()` on my cursor and when change occur i just notify that change happened.
i looked into the [notifyChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean)) method on android developer and i didnt see any way to pass some metadata .

when i said metadata i meant any other object which tell me what change happen like delete/update/insert

Answer (score 0):

You can't specifically add any metadata `per se`, but you can bend the system to pass this information anyway.

When registering your content observer, set the `notifyForDescendants` parameter to true. Then in your `ContentProvider`, generate a different uri to add information.

For example if the uri you normally use is `content://com.example.app.provider/item/42`, you can use one of the following uris to add information :

- `content://com.example.app.provider/item/42/inserted`
- `content://com.example.app.provider/item/42/updated`
- `content://com.example.app.provider/item/42/deleted`